# Show a subset of context-menu items based on the content of the selected text (firefox addon)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, contextmenu, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a firefox context menu with a `selectionContext` and three items on that menu. In the menu I have a content script which listens for an `onclick` event and it gets the item that was clicked and the selected text. That all works fine.

```
Menu
    item1
    item2
    item3
```

I am trying to only show a subset of the menu items based on the content of the selected text as not all of them will apply in all cases.

In addition to the above I have tried to add a `selectionContext` and another content script to each item  which listens for `on context`. Using this method I can get the selected text but the item never shows in the menu because it is cancelled out by the item's content script which listens for an `oncontext` event. The Menu's `onclick` content script is then never applied to the item.

I know I can add and remove Items with `menu.addItem()` and `menu.removeItem()`. If I use the `onclick` content script the items will not be updated until after they are clicked by which point it is too late but I must keep the `onclick` so the user can click the items. If I add an `oncontext` content script to the items or the menu then the items or menu do not show because the `oncontext` beats the `onclick`.

I would be grateful if anyone could advise me on how to show a subset of menu items that can use an on click content script based on the content of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sorted it by using a `predicateContext` in addition to the `selectionContext`.

```
//context attribute of the Menu
context: [contextMenu.PredicateContext(checkText),contextmenu.selectionContext()]




function checkText(data) {

       if(data.selectionText === null)
           return false;

       console.log('selectionText: ' + data.selectionText);

       //handle showing or hiding of menu items based on the text content.
       menuItemToggle(data.selectionText);

       return true;
};

function menuItemToggle(text){
    // do stuff here

};
```